# Svelte img error handler not getting called

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to build a simple component in Svelte. Image component with fallback in case the src is invalid. This is my code and it doesn't work. I've tried many variations (on:error instead of onError, listen to error on mount which was sometimes too late) but none worked.
Any idea what is the right approach?

```
<script>
    import TCFavIcon from '@src/common/icons/TCFavIcon.png';

    export let src = TCFavIcon;
    export let alt = undefined;

    function handleError() {
        console.log('error'); // This never happen even when src is invalid
        src = TCFavIcon;
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>

<img onError={handleError} {alt} {src} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:
`<img on:error={handleError} {alt} {src} />`
[Svelte docs here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dom-events)

Comment: any updates on that? It doesnt seem to work in svelte ^v3.5