# Fall back image with SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I got started with Svelte(Kit) and I really like it so far. However, I ran into an issue that I couldn't resolve.

I'm trying to dynamically display images and like to have a fall back image in case the normal one does not exist.

With vanilla HTML/JS, I would use this [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#element.onerror):

```
<img src="imagefound.gif" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='imagenotfound.gif';" />
```

I tried to make it happen in my Svelte project, but it either does not work (e.g. A) or it works sometimes (for a brief moment or until I refresh (e.g. B)).

This is my code (A):

```
<script>
let profileImg = person.profile;
const missingProfile = () => {
    console.log('image does not exist');
    profileImg = '../default.png';
};
</script>

...

<img
    src={profileImg}
    on:error={missingProfile}
    alt={person.name}
/>
```

or just the hardcoded version (B)

```
<img 
    src="imagefound.gif" 
    onerror="console.log('image not found');this.onerror=null;this.src='./person.png';" 
/>
```

---

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877254/svelte-img-error-handler-not-getting-called), but I believe the answer is what I am doing. Is there a difference whether I use SvelteKit vs. Svelte?

### Addition

It looks like that Svelte does not even set the `src` for the `<img />`, if the original variable with the url for the image is `undefined` (in my example `person.profile`). The accepted answer wouldn't work in that case.

I edited this line to prevent that case:

```
let profileImg = person.profile === undefined ? '../default.png' : person.profile;
```

Comment: concerning your addition: yes this is correct, the svelte compiler does not add the attributes if the value is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works in SvelteKit

```html
<script>
    let fallback = 'http://placekitten.com/200/200'
    let image = ""
    
    const handleError = ev => ev.target.src = fallback
</script>

<img src={image} alt="" on:error={handleError}>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to display a different element when the image was not found. With the help I found on this page about using `on:error={}`, I was able to do this:

```
{#if image}
    <img
        class="image"
        src={image.url}
        alt="..."
        on:error={() => image = undefined}
    >
{:else}
    <div class="fallback"> ... </div>
{/if}
```

This way I can handle both scenarios: when the image is not set, and when the image is set but not found. In the event that the image is set but not found, the `image` variable will be set to `undefined` and Svelte will then use the `:else` part and display my other element.